# Calculate the differential at a point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm to calculate the differential to $f(x_1,x_2)=e^{x_1}+x_2$ at $x=(2,-1)$

I get the differential to be: $e^{x_1}dx_1+dx_2$

I'm ready to plug in the coordinates (only $x_1$) but I'm put off by the "$dx_1$" and "$dx_2$", how do I deal with them if I only want a value as an output?

Comment: `e^{x_1}` gives $e^{x_1}$.

Comment: Are u sure that it's not $f(x,y)=e^x+y$ ?

Comment: I think you are mixing things up. What you want to calculate is the linear transformation $df_x\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ at the point $x=(2, -1)$. In this case, I don't see why do you need to talk about $dx_1$ and $dx_2$ (I guess you are treating $f$ as a $0$-form, and then thinking of the $1$-form $df=\omega$, and thinking in $\omega_x$, and that's correct, but it is a lot simpler than that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$, and $x\in \mathbb R^n$, you can compute the differential of $f$ at $x$, $df_x \colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ as follows.

If $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$, then $df_x$ is given by $$d f_{x}(v)= (\nabla f)_{x}\cdot v$$

Then, for $f(x_1,x_2)=e^{x_1}+x_2$ and $x=(2,-1)$ you have that $(\nabla f)_x=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x), \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x)\right)=(e^2, 1)$. And for any $v=(v_1, v_2)\in \mathbb R^2$, you have that
$$df_x(v)=e^2v_1+v_2.$$